# How to Thread a Tweepy Stream

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, twitter, tweepy

I am making a program that pulls live tweets using Tweepy, and runs it through a function. I am using a Tweepy Stream to accomplish the task of getting the tweets. However, what I wish is that while the function is running, Tweepy can still pull these live tweets. I believe I need to thread the Tweepy event listener but I'm not entirely sure how to do this.

```
def doesSomething(s):
    #function here

class listener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    def on_status(self, status):
        doesSomething(status)

stream_listener = listener()
tweepy.Stream(auth = api.auth, listener=stream_listener)
stream.filter(track=["Example"])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example you can adapt easily... 
The code will create a thread that updates a counter in the background while a loop will continuously print the value of the counter. The 'stop' variable takes care of quitting the thread when the main process is killed or exit...

```
import threading
import time
from sys import stdout

# Only data wihtin a class are actually shared by the threads
class Counter(object):
    counter = 0
    stop = False

# Function that will be executed in parallel with the rest of the code
def function_1():
    for i in range(10):
        if c.stop: return # With more will exit faster
        time.sleep(2)
        c.counter += 1
        if c.stop: return

# Create a class instance
c = Counter()

# Thread function_1
d = threading.Thread(target=function_1)
d.start()

# Exit the thread properly before exiting...
try:
    for j in range(100):
        stdout.write('\r{:}'.format(c.counter))
        stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(1)
except:
    c.stop = True
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the async=True parameter to run the stream in another thread:

```
myStream.filter(track=['python'], async=True)
```

See http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.5.0/streaming_how_to.html for more information.

Comment: In newer versions use `is_async=True`